# local RHEL 8 apache webserver not available from different subnet

Tags: linux, rhel, apache-httpd, subnets

I have setup a small apache webserver on a RHEL 8 VM that is accessible to machines on that particular subnet (10.x.x.x), but not on another subnet (172.x.x.x).  This webserver has no internet access.

I have tried temporarily disabling firewalld as well as SELinux when troubleshooting, but neither made a difference.

From my Windows machine on a 172.x.x.x IP (website doesn't work), I get this in Powershell:

```
> tnc 172.22.6.9 -port 80
WARNING: TCP connect to (172.22.6.9 : 80) failed


ComputerName           : 172.22.6.9
RemoteAddress          : 172.22.6.9
RemotePort             : 80
InterfaceAlias         : Ethernet 3
SourceAddress          : 172.16.195.117
PingSucceeded          : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 31 ms
TcpTestSucceeded       : False
```

On my other machine on the 10.x.x.x subnet (where the website works) I get this:

```
> tnc 172.22.6.9 -port 80


ComputerName     : 172.22.6.9
RemoteAddress    : 172.22.6.9
RemotePort       : 80
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet
SourceAddress    : 10.0.236.53
TcpTestSucceeded : True
```

Tcpdump shows this below.  I am ssh'ed in, so I believe this is whats showing up for port 22:

```
$ tcpdump -nn -i ens192 | grep 172.16.195.117
dropped privs to tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ens192, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
 08:23:28.730189 IP 172.22.6.9.22 > 172.16.195.117.50600: Flags [P.], seq 664703141:664703221, ack 3210526827, win 488, length 80
08:23:28.730354 IP 172.22.6.9.22 > 172.16.195.117.50600: Flags [P.], seq 80:176, ack 1, win 488, length 96
08:23:28.730574 IP 172.22.6.9.22 > 172.16.195.117.50600: Flags [P.], seq 176:304, ack 1, win 488, length 128
08:23:28.730676 IP 172.22.6.9.22 > 172.16.195.117.50600: Flags [P.], seq 304:400, ack 1, win 488, length 96
08:23:28.730761 IP 172.22.6.9.22 > 172.16.195.117.50600: Flags [P.], seq 400:528, ack 1, win 488, length 128
08:23:28.730839 IP 172.22.6.9.22 > 172.16.195.117.50600: Flags [P.], seq 528:624, ack 1, win 488, length 96
08:23:28.760000 IP 172.16.195.117.50600 > 172.22.6.9.22: Flags [.], ack 624, win 1022, length 0
08:23:35.942843 IP 172.22.6.9.22 > 172.16.195.117.50600: Flags [P.], seq 624:896, ack 1, win 488, length 272
08:23:36.023088 IP 172.16.195.117.50600 > 172.22.6.9.22: Flags [.], ack 896, win 1021, length 0
08:24:01.938129 IP 172.22.6.9.22 > 172.16.195.117.50600: Flags [P.], seq 896:1200, ack 1, win 488, length 304
08:24:02.017682 IP 172.16.195.117.50600 > 172.22.6.9.22: Flags [.], ack 1200, win 1025, length 0
08:24:05.957775 IP 172.22.6.9.22 > 172.16.195.117.50600: Flags [P.], seq 1200:1472, ack 1, win 488, length 272
08:24:06.035691 IP 172.16.195.117.50600 > 172.22.6.9.22: Flags [.], ack 1472, win 1024, length 0
08:25:01.976052 IP 172.22.6.9.22 > 172.16.195.117.50600: Flags [P.], seq 1472:1776, ack 1, win 488, length 304
08:25:02.051839 IP 172.16.195.117.50600 > 172.22.6.9.22: Flags [.], ack 1776, win 1023, length 0
08:25:05.991836 IP 172.22.6.9.22 > 172.16.195.117.50600: Flags [P.], seq 1776:2048, ack 1, win 488, length 272
08:25:06.066825 IP 172.16.195.117.50600 > 172.22.6.9.22: Flags [.], ack 2048, win 1022, length 0
08:25:33.318464 IP 172.16.195.117 > 172.22.6.9: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 282, length 40
08:25:33.318493 IP 172.22.6.9 > 172.16.195.117: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 282, length 40
```

Where would you all start looking, even if the firewall service is disabled?

The file - /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf shows `Listen 80`

One thing I did noticed while firewalld was running was the "trusted" zone didn't have the 172.x.x.x CIDR address listed.  I'm not sure if this matters though because firewalld is disabled right now:

```
$ firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
libvirt
  interfaces: virbr0
public
  interfaces: ens192
trusted
  sources: 10.0.0.0/16
```

The output of this command

```
firewall-cmd --get-active-zones | grep -P '^[^\s]' | xargs -I{} firewall-cmd --info-zone={}


libvirt (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: virbr0
  sources:
  services: dhcp dhcpv6 dns ssh tftp
  ports:
  protocols: icmp ipv6-icmp
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
        rule priority="32767" reject
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens192
  sources:
  services: http https ssh
  ports: 3389/tcp 9524/tcp 9524/udp 80/tcp 443/tcp
  protocols:
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
trusted (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources: 10.0.0.0/16
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Also:

```
grep -PRn '^\s*Listen\s+' /etc/httpd 2>/dev/null
```

shows:

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:45:Listen 80
```

Any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: does the webserver listen on both addresses?

Comment: Did you solve the issue, yet? If not, how about posting the output of ```firewall-cmd --info-zone=...``` for each one of those zones listed by ```firewall-cmd --get-active-zones``` (or in one single command: ```firewall-cmd --get-active-zones | grep -P '^[^\s]' | xargs -I{} firewall-cmd --info-zone={}```). Also, can you post the output of running ```grep -PRn '^\s*Listen\s+' /etc/httpd 2>/dev/null```?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and sorry for the delay.  I just now received an email notification about the comments.  I added the output to the original post.